# Info about 3MF file format (for 3D printing)

Tags: windows, printing, 3d

Microsoft announced new support for 3D printing in Windows 8.1. They invented a new file format called 3MF for communicating with the printer.

Does anyone have any kind of spec for the 3MF file format, or even any detailed information about it? I'm especially interested in how geometry is represented.

Also, any thoughts on how 3MF might co-exist with the existing AMF format? Are the two formats competing or complementary?

Answer (score 2):

You can request the Microsoft 3D Printing SDK (which includes the 3D Manufacturing Format spec) at ask3dprint at microsoft dot com.

Geometry is represented very similarly to AMF, with a more compact (fewer bytes) format.

3MF is intended to be a native 3D spool file format in the Windows print pipeline, something which AMF could not be (due to flaws in the spec, reported to ASTM). 3MF and AMF are not the same, but they follow a similar design approach. Since 3MF supports custom metadata, it is possible to transform an AMF document into 3MF format (and back).

3MF does not support curved triangles or a scripting language, however. 3D printing makers generally aren't really using those anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The spec can be downloaded here:
 http://3mf.io/what-is-3mf/3mf-specification

I read the spec, and it stores individual mesh vertices with XML tags.

And, this is justified as follows: "The variable-precision nature of ASCII encoding is a significant advantage over fixed-width binary formats, and helps make up the difference in storage efficiency."

Anyone doing web coding knows that XML tags can eat up >60% of storage space. Just compare the number of bytes used for xml tags vs useful data. And, it requires more CPU time to parse. In addition, storing digits in variable-width ASCII is still longer in bytes than fixed-width double precision IEEE.

This essentially cripples 3MF for handling large meshes.. Unless of course, the companies involved develop their own proprietary extension that overcomes this.

I make a call for consumers and users to openly reject the current 3MF spec until the 3MF consortium fixes this particular aspect. Modify the public spec to include an alternative binary format section for vertex / normal / index/ streaming.